# Solving the integral equation $y(x)=e^{-x^2/2}+\lambda\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-i(x-z)}y(z)dz$

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, fundamental-solution

Could you please help me to solve the following integral equation?

> $$y(x)=e^{-x^2/2}+\lambda\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-i(x-z)}y(z)dz$$
> I tried to turn the exponentiential term into its trigonometric form and tried to solve the equation obtain in term of new constants $c_1=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}cos(z)y(z)dz$ and $c_2=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}sinz(z)y(z)dz$. But I obtained for $c_1$
> $$c_1=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}cos(z)e^{-z^2/2}dz+\lambda (c_1+ic_2)\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}cos^2(z)dz+\lambda(c_2-c_1i)\times\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}cos(z)sinzdz.$$
> I can't go further.

I also applied the Fourier transform on both sides and obtained that this equation has a unique solution iff $$1-\lambda\hat{K}(\alpha)\neq 0$$ where $$\hat{K}(\alpha)$$ is the Fourier transform of $e^{-ix}$. But I think (I am not sure) the Fourier transform of such a function is the dirac function $\delta_{-\alpha}$, and I don't know how to proceed.

Please need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have already a Fourier Transform in the RHS because your equation is $y(x)=e^{-x^2/2}+\lambda e^{-ix}\underbrace{\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{iz}y(z)dz}_{\hat{y}(a)}$ where $a=-1/(2 \pi)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie. And answer is?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414562/functional-equation-with-fourier-transform-and-frac1x-f-frac1x?rq=1

Comment: What is your definition of Fourier transform (there are at least two of them) ? And what has been given to you as the Fourier Transform of $e^{-t^2/2}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the equation has a solution only if $\lambda=0$.

Let $y(x)$ be a solution. Multiply both sides with $e^{ix}$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
  w(x)=e^{ix-x^2/2}+\lambda\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w(z)\,\mathrm{d}z,\tag {1}
\end{equation}
where $w(x)=e^{ix}y(x)$. Put
\begin{equation*}
 C =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w(z)\,\mathrm{d}z.
\end{equation*}
Then $C$ is a constant and $w(x)= e^{ix-x^2/2}+\lambda C $. However, the integral in $(1)$ is convergent. Thus $\lambda C = 0$.

If $C=0$ then $w(x)= e^{ix-x^2/2}$ and
\begin{equation*}
 C=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w(z)\,\mathrm{d}z= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{iz-z^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}z =\sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi}{e}} \neq 0.
\end{equation*}
What remains is the alternative $\lambda= 0$.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you!!!